# How can I pass variables from hybrid .php/HTML file to another .php file? -- I've tried all the methods I've found on-line

Tags: php, html, session

I'm coding up a website page (a .php file that is mostly an HTML page with some needed .php functionality in it) for my high school graduating class that has a "rest in peace" (RIP.php) page.  The RIP page has an image slider that pulls a deceased classmate's info from a MySQL database to display a picture of them, their obituary, and will have the ability to post a comment there before scrolling to the next deceased classmate. To make the Comment functionality work, I made a hidden form that reveals itself when you click on an "Add a comment" button under the obituary. That form once filled in and submitted needs to call another .php file (updateComment.php) as a submit action that does a CONCAT to the Comments field of that deceased classmate's record.  Into that file I need to pass the deceased classmates first and last name, so the Comment CONCAT is done on the proper classmates Comments field.

I've tried using SESSION variables, but that requires me to do a
`<? php session_start() ?>` at the very top of my .php/HTML file which apparently can't be closed until the Session variable is defined (3/4s of the way through the page's code), so that doesn't work.

I've tried passing the variables (first and last name) in as hidden form elements that the updateComments.php file is supposed to be able to grab using $_POST, but I can't seem to make that work either.

**It might help if I could figure out how set a breakpoint on the updateComments.php file** which isn't called until the form submit and exits before I can catch it using "inspect" from the Chrome debugger.

Here is the pertinent part of my code so far with the non-working session variable method:

**RIP.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN
http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<?php
   session_start(); // start session for transfer of ClassmateNameFirst and 
   ClassmateNameLast to updateComments
?>
<head>
...
<div class="riparea">
  <?php
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "classmateinfo");
  if ($conn-> connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed:". $conn-> connect_error);
  }
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM rip ORDER BY DeathDate";
  $result = $conn-> query($sql);
  if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
      $i = 0;
      while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
        $_SESSION['fname'] = $row["ClassmateNameFirst"];
        $_SESSION['lname'] = $row["ClassmateNameLast"];
...
        echo "<div><form id=\"formElement\" style=\"display: none;\" action=\"updateComment.php\">";
        echo "<div class=\"formitemname\">Name:</div>";
        echo "<input class=\"formitem shortentry\" type=\"text\" maxlength=\"40\" value=\"\" id=\"commentor\" name=\"commentor\" placeholder=\"Your Name\">";
        echo "<div class=\"formitemnamelonger\">Your Memory or Story of $name:</div>";
        echo "<textarea class=\"formitem longentry\" type=\"text\" maxlength=\"2000\" value=\"\" id=\"memory-story\" name=\"memory-story\" placeholder=\"Add your memory or story here\" rows=\"5\"></textarea>";
        echo "<button style=\"text-align: center; margin: 10px 0 10px 240px;\" type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" id=\"submit\">Submit</button>";
        echo "</form></div>";
```

**updateComment.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "classmateinfo");
  if ($conn-> connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed:". $conn-> connect_error);
  }
  $_SESSION['fname'] = $firstname;
  $_SESSION['lname'] = $lastname;
  $memory = !empty($_POST['memory-story'])?$_POST['memory-story']:'';
  $name = !empty($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:'';
  $toappend = $memory + "<br>-- " + $name;

  $sql = "UPDATE rip SET Comment = CONCAT(Comment,'$toappend') WHERE ClassmateNameFirst = '$firstname' AND ClassmateNameLast = '$lastname'";
  $result = $conn-> query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: Place `session_start();` before _any_ output in your file

Comment: You cannot do that with a session. What you need here is just a trivial hidden input.

Comment: brombeer - Are you telling me to add the session start above the DOCTYPE statement?

Comment: it shouldn't be the first and last name though, but the **unique id** from the rip table

Comment: Your Common Sense - I tried that but I couldn't make the hidden input show up on the updateComment.php side.  I don't know how to set a breakpoint on the updateComment.php file to see what is showing up on the other side.

Comment: And it should be a separate table comments, not a single column in the rip table

Comment: var_dump($_POST);die; should do

Comment: Your Common Sense - the unique id (Primary field) is a combo of ClassmateNameFirst and ClassmateNameLast.

Comment: Your Common Sense - the CONCAT statement appends the comment to the end of the Comment field.  That is what I want to do, not create a bunch of separate comments that need to be displayed separately.

Comment: Your Common Sense - so I add var_dump($POST);die; in my updateComment.php file at the top after adding back in the hidden vinputs?